# How can I set the field to JSON in MongooseJS?

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

My Mongoose model is:

```
var Schema = new Schema({
  code: String,
  type: String,
  people:{}
}
```

and data for items is :

```
people :  
    {
        "id":"2342423",
        "name":"John"
    },
    {
        "id":"1231231",
        "name":"Marry"
    }
```

when I write:

```
    var obj = new Schema({
            people:people});
```

obj.people is {}. Where am I wrong?

Comment: people is not valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have isn't valid JSON. The top level needs to be a single object or array, so you might want something like the following:

```
people: [
    {
        "id":"2342423",
         "name":"John"
    },
    {
        "id":"1231231",
        "name":"Marry"
    }
]
```

That's a single array, containing objects that have information about two people.

Comment: I see, but that is coming from web service. How can I convert it to valid JSON?

Comment: @Burak I don't know enough about the technologies you're using to help with that, unfortunately. I know how JSON objects should be structured, that's it. Though if you're getting two separate objects back from a request to a web service, sounds like the server part is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

people should be of type Object or Array